# Seems that $(this).parents doesn't work for me

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a delete button on the right. When these button are clicked, I have an ajax call. On the OnComplete event, I have this code:

```
function JsonDelete_OnComplete(data) {

    var json = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);

    if (json.Success) {
        $(this).parents("tr.item").remove();
    }

}
```

The event is fired. I try to remove the deleted line but it doesn't work. Can you help me? I'm sure the problem is on the $(this).... line

My table is formatted as this:

```
<table>
  <tr class="item">
      <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(m => person.FirstName)
      </td>
      <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(m => person.LastName)
      </td>
      <td align="right">
          @Ajax.ActionLink("delete", "JsonDelete", "People", new { Id = person.Id }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Are you sure you want to Delete this Person? This action cannot be undone.", HttpMethod = "Delete", OnComplete = "JsonDelete_OnComplete" })
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can try to see the error with the firebug in Firefox. This may give you some ideas for solve problem.

Comment: Thanks I don't know firebug but I'll investigate...

Comment: What is `@Ajax.ActionLink`? It doesn't seem to be in jQuery. Anyway, `this` is most probably not what you think in your `JsonDelete_OnComplete`. I suggest you look at the documentation for `@Ajax.ActionLink` and see if you can find some way of binding it to the current element (your click target).

Comment: Ajax.ActionLink is specific to asp.net mvc.

Comment: Ok - well, if it can't bind to the click target, and if it doesn't pass the event to your `JsonDelete_OnComplete`, there is no way for you to find out what element was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

you should try,

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("delete", "JsonDelete", "People", new { Id = person.Id }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Are you sure you want to Delete this Person? This action cannot be undone.", HttpMethod = "Delete", OnComplete = "JsonDelete_OnComplete(data,this)" })

function JsonDelete_OnComplete(data,element) {

    var json = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);

    if (json.Success) {
        $(element).parents("tr.item").remove();
    }

}
```